# how to find total price

Tags: python

I don't know how to get the all total price of the product that the customer bought from my system. the price of each item I can get but the price of all the item that have been choose i can't get the output. I'm using python.

Below is my code:

```
#below is the price of products

shopping_cart = {}
option = 1

while option!= 0:
    option = int(input("What type of milk you want to purchased: "))

    if option == 1:
       print("coke")
       qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
       total = qnty*8.49
    elif option == 2:
         print("dutch lady")
         qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
         total = qnty*8.50
    elif option == 3:
         print("fanta")
         total = qnty*3.00
    elif option == 4:
         print("Yoghurt")
         qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
         total = qnty*16.50
    elif option == 5:
         print("pepsi")
         qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
         total = qnty*18.50
    elif option == 6:
         print("beer")
         qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
         total = qnty*20.70
    else:
        ("Not found")

def totalcart (pr,qnty):       #is my code correct here?
    totalcart = (pr * qny)
    return total
print("The total price in your cart is ", (total))
break
print("Come Again")
```

Comment: There are some common mistakes in your code that a lot of newbies make. First, you are repeating a lot of code. You already have a dictionary with item/milk names but you are writing it again when a user is entering the option. Second, you are defining a function when you have to use it only once. Third, checking each condition individually like `elif option ==2:` etc. @Tim Robert's answer is correct but it will be really good if you can improve on the above points as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting `("Not found")` as a statement doesn't print anything.  You need to add your item total into `total_cost` immediately after the print statement.  There's no point defining a function, since you don't call the function.  So, replace everything after that last "else:" with this:

```
    else:
        total = 0
        print("Not found")
    total_cost += total

print("The total price in your cart is RM ", total_cost)
print("Please Come Again")
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir and finally i got it the total price

Answer (score 0):

You can add `total_cost += total` for every choice,
So its added to the total cost when somebody choose the item and if he add another it also adds to the total cost.

```py
elif option == 6:
         print("Foaming Milk")
         qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
         total = qnty*12.70
         print("The price is: " + str(total)) 
         total_cost += total
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You basically have the same couple lines for every option
2. You dont save your values

You can try this:

```
items = {
    "UHT Milk" : 6.49, 
    "Pasteurised Milk" : 5.50, 
    "Sterilised Milk" : 4.00, 
    "Eating and Drinking Yoghurt" : 10.50, 
    "Full Cream Milk" : 15.50, 
    "Foaming Milk" :12.70
    }


shopping_cart = {}
total_cost = 0

while True:
    option = int(input("What type of milk you want to purchase: "))
    if option == 0: break

    elif option == 1: milk = "UHT Milk" 
    elif option == 2: milk = "Pasteurised Milk"
    elif option == 3: milk = "Sterilised Milk" 
    elif option == 4: milk = "Eating and Drinking Yoghurt"
    elif option == 5: milk = "Full Cream Milk" 
    elif option == 6: milk = "Foaming Milk"
    else:
        print("Not found")
        continue

    print(milk)
    qnty = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
    shopping_cart[milk] = qnty

    total = qnty*items[milk]
    total_cost += total
    print("The price for this product(s) is: " + str(total))
    print('The total price is: %.2f' % total_cost)
    
    
print("\nThe total price in your cart is %.2f " % total_cost)
print("Please Come Again")
```

also you already had the dictionary with names and prices but didnt use it.
just get the price from the items dictionary, but make sure that the name is the same as the option or else you get a KeyError.

Since Python 3.10 you could also use match case if you like that a bit more.
just replace all elif's with this:

```
match option:
    case 1: milk = "UHT Milk" 
    case 2: milk = "Pasteurised Milk"
    case 3: milk = "Sterilised Milk" 
    case 4: milk = "Eating and Drinking Yoghurt"
    case 5: milk = "Full Cream Milk" 
    case 6: milk = "Foaming Milk"
    case _: 
        print("Not found")
        continue
```

Comment: @ dozing _off i want to how to add "How many product do you want?"

Comment: @ dozing_off can i know how to add "how many product want " in the python you done for me. Thank in advance.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, so far every order is added to shopping_cart with the milk name as key and the quantity as value if thats what you mean...